# Items inside table row wont align center to each column

Tags: css, css-tables

I created a table that looks as follows:

[image]

For some reason I cant center the numbers inside each row to be centered with the header.

My HTML is as follows (I use Flask so that's why the for loop):

```
<div class="calculation_grid">
    <ul class="responsive-table">
        <li class="table-header">
            {% for cell in headings %}
            <div class="col"> {{ cell }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
        {% for row in data %}
        <li class="table-row">
            {% for cell in row %}
            <div class="col"> {{ cell }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.responsive-table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout : fixed;
}

.responsive-table li {
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-table .table-header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.responsive-table .table-row {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white;
}

.responsive-table .table-row .col {
  text-align: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 100%) {
  .responsive-table .table-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-table li {
    display: block;
  }
  .responsive-table .col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

Any idea why it won't center?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with grid:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.responsive-table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout : fixed;
}

.responsive-table li {
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-table .table-header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.responsive-table .table-row {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 254, 5, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white;
}

.responsive-table .table-row .col {
  text-align: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 100%) {
  .responsive-table .table-header {
    display: none;
  }
  .responsive-table li {
    display: block;
  }
  .responsive-table .col {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="calculation_grid">
  <ul class="responsive-table">
    <li class="table-header">
      <div class="col"> image</div>
      <div class="col"> item</div>
      <div class="col"> amount</div>
      <div class="col"> xp each</div>
      <div class="col"> gp required</div>
      <div class="col"> gp obtained</div>
    </li>
    <li class="table-row">
      <div class="col"> 1</div>
      <div class="col"> 2</div>
      <div class="col"> 3</div>
      <div class="col"> 4</div>
      <div class="col"> 5</div>
      <div class="col"> 6</div>
    </li>
    <li class="table-row">
      <div class="col"> 1</div>
      <div class="col"> 2</div>
      <div class="col"> 3</div>
      <div class="col"> 4</div>
      <div class="col"> 5</div>
      <div class="col"> 6</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```